# Bluetooth connection issue

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, bluez

I have a problem with my Bluetooth connection
When I connect my earbuds (Soundcore life p3) it connects normally and detected as Headset, but it doesn't appear in the sound settings until I reconfigure bluez using this code line:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure bluez
```

how can I resolve this annoying problem?